# geolocation is not active android adobe flash as3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm creating a simple geolocation app for android in adobe flash as3.

I'm using the example code found [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/quick_start_as/quickstarts/qs_as_geolocation_api.html)

however, I get no geolocation information (longitude or latitude) and instead I get this in my app:

```
geoStatus.text = "GPS not active!";
```

I have checked my Android device and I know the location access in enabled and I can also confirm that by using the google location map app on my device.

so it really doesn't make sense that it doesn't work in my app all i get is **GPS not active** error!

my phone has android 4.2.2 installed on it.

the question that I have is that is this a common issue with adobe air for android and what are the fixes to solve this issue?

I have searched all over the internet and all i could find is the information about HTML5!

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us your code because we have no idea what's "geoStatus.text" and how it got the value "GPS not active!" ? I tried the same example and It works fine.

Comment: @akmozo, there is something wrong with my android phone. because i tried the same code in an iphone and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

check your application descriptor file (aplication_name-app.xml)

```
<android> <manifestAdditions> 
  <![CDATA[<manifest> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />     </manifest>]]>
   </manifestAdditions>  
</android>
```